# Declare mutually recursive types

Tags: ats

I have the following two types that are mutually recursive (they have pointers pointing to each other):

```
vtypedef SimpleTextOutputInterface =
   @{ reset = EfiTextReset
    , output_string = [l:addr] (EfiTextString@l | ptr l)
    }

vtypedef EfiTextString = [n:nat][l1,l2:addr] (SimpleTextOutputInterface@l1, @[uint16][n]@l2 | ptr l1, ptr l2) -> uint64
```

I tried declaring an abstract type, like this:

```
absvt@ype SimpleTextOutputInterface

vtypedef EfiTextString = [n:nat][l1,l2:addr] (SimpleTextOutputInterface@l1, @[uint16][n]@l2 | ptr l1, ptr l2) -> uint64

assume SimpleTextOutputInterface =
   @{ reset = EfiTextReset
    , output_string = [l:addr] (EfiTextString@l | ptr l)
    }
```

But I have type errors when I try to use them (as though an at-view is lost somewhere).

Is there a way to make this work?
Maybe with a forward declaration if that exists in ATS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My "standard" approach is to introduce a dummy and some related proof functions:

```
abst@ype SimpleTextOutputInterface_

prfun encode :
{l:addr} SimpleTextOutputInterface @l -> SimpleTextOutputInterface_@l
prfun decode :
{l:addr} SimpleTextOutputInterface_@l -> SimpleTextOutputInterface @l
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error: `unsolved constraint: C3NSTRprop(C3TKmain(); S2Eeqeq(S2Evar(k$957(4282)); S2Evar(l1$958(4283))))` as though the location in the at-view was changed by the `encode` function. How can I fix this?